# Google Drive - Root Folder Id

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

Is the Google Drive's Root Folder Id permanent?
Will the Root Folder Id remain the same as long as the account exists?

Answer (score 47):

As stated in the [Work with Folders section](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/folder) of the api doc :

> You can use the alias **root** to refer to the root folder anywhere a file ID is provided

That way you'll have the correct id for any user.